# Does h2 support creating table with secondary key?

Tags: sql, h2, ddl, secondary-indexes

Does h2 support creating table with secondary key?

When I try this create table, it fails with "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "("; SQL statement:"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable
    (col1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col2 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col3 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col4 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(col1),
    KEY(col1, col2, col3));
```

But this one succeeds:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable
    (col1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col2 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col3 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col4 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(col1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`KEY` is MySQL-specific syntax:

```
KEY(col1, col2, col3)
```

What you're looking for is a `UNIQUE` constraint, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable (
    col1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col2 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col3 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col4 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (col1),
    UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3)
);
```

Note, I usually like to name my constraints, because that will allow for easier finding / dropping them later on:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable (
    col1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col2 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col3 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    col4 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (col1),
    CONSTRAINT secondary_key UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3)
);
```

#### In case you're not looking for uniqueness

Interestingly (as pointed out also in the comments), MySQL uses the term `KEY` for non-unique indexes. In most databases (including MySQL), you would simply create an index for this case:

```
CREATE INDEX secondary_index ON testTable(col1, col2, col3);
```

Comment: Not also that you can use `INDEX` instead of the mysql specific `KEY` , if you just want a normal index (without the constraint of the column combination being unique)

Comment: @nos: Good point. I forgot about this interesting MySQL interpretation of what a `KEY` is